# How to create /ardrone/takeoff topic manually?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ardrone, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/ardrone/takeoff topic is missing in my rostopic list command
So how do I create takeoff node manually such that my drone can fly ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286822/how-to-create-/ardrone/takeoff-topic-manually-?/) by [shubham11](https://answers.ros.org/users/34180/shubham11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-27**:
Th presence (or absence) of this topic is a symptom that you're not running the node which provides it. You should figure out which node that is for your drone, configure it correctly and run it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-27**:
It would help to know which drone you have and which commands, nodes or launch files you're already running.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-28**:
I just noticed that your other question (#q286063) says that you're using the a simulator, is that still true?

**Comment by [shubham11](https://answers.ros.org/users/34180/shubham11/) on 2018-03-28**:
Yes I'm still using the a simulator

**Comment by [shubham11](https://answers.ros.org/users/34180/shubham11/) on 2018-03-28**:
@ahendrix you are suggesting that I should configure the node correctly, well there are only 3 nodes and none of them is having access to the /takeoff topic

**Comment by [shubham11](https://answers.ros.org/users/34180/shubham11/) on 2018-03-28**:
@ahendrix how do I configure the node?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-28**:
I have no idea. You still haven't completed the first step of identifying the correct software for your drone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd say that you *shouldn't* create this topic manually as @ahendrix says in the comments of your question. As your question #q286063 shows, you're getting

```
Getting AR.Drone version ...
```

repeated which may mean that you're not connected to the drone. Manually creating the `/ardrone/takeoff` topic won't do anything useful.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0